# mutt sidebar: expand/collapse folders

Tags: mutt

Is there a way to expand/collapse a single folder or all folders in the `mutt-patched` sidebar? I couldn't find anything about this in the sidebar [documentation](http://www.lunar-linux.org/mutt-sidebar/).

Answer (score 3):

Actually I have some idea how to implement this using a configuration file.

You have maildirs directory structure like this:

```
~/Mail/
├── account1
│   ├── INBOX
│   │   ├── cur
│   │   ├── new
│   │   └── tmp
│   ├── cur
│   ├── drafts
│   │   ├── cur
│   │   ├── new
│   │   └── tmp
│   ├── new
│   ├── sent
│   │   ├── cur
│   │   ├── new
│   │   └── tmp
│   ├── spam
│   │   ├── cur
│   │   ├── new
│   │   └── tmp
│   └── tmp
└── account2
    ├── INBOX
    │   ├── cur
    │   ├── new
    │   └── tmp
    ├── cur
    ├── drafts
    │   ├── cur
    │   ├── new
    │   └── tmp
    ├── new
    ├── sent
    │   ├── cur
    │   ├── new
    │   └── tmp
    ├── spam
    │   ├── cur
    │   ├── new
    │   └── tmp
    └── tmp
```

Mutt/Neomutt example config (should work in both)

```
# some basic configuration
set folder = ~/Mail
set sidebar_sort_method=alpha
set sidebar_indent_string="  "
set sidebar_folder_indent=yes

# initial mailboxes config
mailboxes `find ~/Mail -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | xargs`

# folder hooks for account1
folder-hook account1$ "unmailboxes *"
folder-hook account1$ "mailboxes `find /tmp/Mail -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | xargs`"
folder-hook account1$ "mailboxes `find /tmp/Mail/account1 -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -name 'new' -not -name 'cur' -not -name 'tmp' | xargs`"

# folder hooks for account2
folder-hook account2$ "unmailboxes *"
folder-hook account2$ "mailboxes `find /tmp/Mail -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | xargs`"
folder-hook account2$ "mailboxes `find /tmp/Mail/account2 -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -name 'new' -not -name 'cur' -not -name 'tmp' | xargs`"

# macro to display all mailboxes
macro index,pager <f5> "<enter-command>mailboxes `find ~/Mail -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type d -not -name 'new' -not -name 'cur' -not -name 'tmp' | xargs`<enter>"
```

- Now when You start neomutt, You'll see only accounts.
- Entering an account mailbox will show You only child mailboxes belonging to the selected account + other account names (without their child mailboxes)
- To display every mailboxes you have I prepared a macro bound to `F5`

[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 2):

Collapsing folder(s) is [not implemented as yet](http://www.lunar-linux.org/mutt-sidebar/). You can request the feature or comment at the [source code repository](http://freecode.com/projects/mutt-folderlist).